# set default parameter to a member variable

Tags: c++, class, parameters

I tried to set a default parameter to a member variable, it gave me this bug.

```
[cquery] invalid use of non-static data member 'num'
```

code

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{
   private:
      int val = 0;
   public:
      void print_num(int num = val){
         std::cout << num << '\n';
      }
}
int main(){
   Test test;
   test.print_num();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite it being quite obvious what this would mean, you just can’t.  The usual workaround is to provide an overload that (implicitly) uses `this` to get the member value.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set a default value for a function parameter to a class member, the member must be static.

Citing the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments),

> Non-static class members are not allowed in default arguments

However, given the context of your code sample I doubt this is what you want to do (as every instance of `Test` class will point to the same `val`. Citing the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent variables

If you make `val` static in your example, and have multiple instances of `Test` in use by your code, you can (and very likely will) have some unexpected behavior. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{
   private:
      static int val;
   public:
      void print_num(int num = val){
         std::cout << num << '\n';
      }
      void set_val(int num) {
          val = num;
      }
}
int Test::val = 0;
int main(){
   Test test1;
   test1.set_val(1);
   Test test2;
   test2.set_val(2);
   test1.print_num(); // results in "2"
   return 0;
}
```

A better alternative would be to pass a pointer to your function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{
   private:
      int val = 0;
   public:
      void print_num(int* numptr = nullptr){
         int num = (numptr ? *numptr : val);
         std::cout << num << '\n';
      }
}
int main(){
   Test test;
   test.print_num();
   return 0;
}
```

Or, as described by Davis Herring, use an overload:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{
   private:
      int val = 0;
   public:
      void print_num(int num){
         std::cout << num << '\n';
      }
      void print_num() {
        return print_num(val); // return is irrelevant here, but my preferred coding style
      }
}
int main(){
   Test test;
   test.print_num();
   return 0;
}
```

Edited to reflect the comment and example.

Comment: *In order to set a default value for a function parameter the value must be known at compile time* [Not true](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Tz5KqKKoY

Comment: @user4581301: Perhaps more interesting, you can call a function, even one which creates a new value out of thin air, in the default argument specification.  However, that doesn't help OP much because you have no access to `this` through which you might access `val`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I figured that was the problem, but my Standard diving didn't explain why you can't do it, just that you can't.

Comment: @user4581301 I think this is an even better example that the value can be evaluated at run time: http://cpp.sh/5gdzs (try entering 42 from the standard input and see the result).

Comment: @user4581301 That's pretty sweet - didn't know you could use non-constant values like that. I've updated my answer, please review and let me know if you see any other errors.

Comment: @heapunderrun, yes - that was a natural extension I picked up on from being able to use non-constant values. Admittedly, I'm not sure I would ever do this (use a static variable as a default parameter value) but it is possible so I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'll be honest with you: I didn't either until I stopped and looked. I've done it with global variables, but never tried it with a class member. Good edit, but I don't think the pointer's the right way to go. An overload as suggested by Davis Herring is much easier on the programmer: `void print_num(){ print_num(val); }`. A decent compiler will optimize that down to next-to-nothing.

Comment: Side note: The issue is currently covered in the Standard at **[dcl.fct.default]** [point 9](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#9) and is strongly suggested by point 8's ban on `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition doesn't actually know what val is because it doesn't actually live inside of your class. The compiler is actually making a function that contains your class as a parameter and abstracts away all of that. You'll want to set num to val within the function body.